# Syntax error in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Why does the following code has a syntax error? I did not find out why.

```
let rec revStr stringa k e = 
if    k = e then ""
else (string_of_char stringa.[e])^
      (revStr stringa (e-1) k);;
```

string `a`, `k`, `e` are the input and it should give in output the `sub.string` from integer `e` to integer `k`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntax error in this code. When I try it I get "Unbound value: string_of_char" which is a type error. Type errors appear after syntax errors, because typing occurs after parsing.

My guess is that you have a syntax error before this function, such as a forgotten semi-colon or a forgotten "in". Those kinds of errors are often detected much later.

Comment: Thanks but now i have out a serious error: "Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?)."

Comment: Are you sure you meant `revStr stringa (e-1) k` and not `revStr stringa k (e-1)`?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what cygin points out (parameters seem reversed), `revStr` calls itself with a *smaller* value for `e`. But your description sounds like `e` is supposed to be less than or equal `k`. So then wouldn't you want to pass a *larger* value for `e`? Otherwise I don't see why you would ever reach `k`.

As a side comment, I wonder why a substring function is named `revStr`.